# Unusual problem with the Runtime error 91 – Object variable or With block variable not set

Tags: vba

I’m having an unusual problem with the Runtime error 91 – Object variable or With block variable not set. I have an application I created to balance banking account transactions from I workbook that contains all of my financial transactions. An initial form is used to select an account, get fees, interest paid and interest earned. This form launches a second form that dynamically displays the transactions from that account that have not been reconciled. This second form has a frame where I dynamically add controls to for each transaction. For instance, I use dynamically created labels for the transaction date, payee, and amount. I also dynamically add a checkbox to each row. To clear a transaction, you simply check the checkbox. I had to create an event handler for managing the clicking of the checkbox. All of this works great for accounts that have transactions to be reconciled.

When no unreconciled transactions are found, I have a msgbox pop up to inform me and the form unloads. This is where I get the runtime error. What’s odd to me is that I get the error  after the Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose, i.e. the form is unloaded. This is my first form using dynamically created controls and custom event handlers. I’m guessing this is where my issue is.  It seems it needs to go through the loop where I create the dynamically controls are created.

Below is the code in the Class module for the event handler followed by the Initiate and QueryClose subroutines.

Is there something I’m missing about using dynamically added controls or custom event handlers? I appreciate the help.

```
Option Explicit
Public WithEvents CheckBoxEvents As MSForms.CheckBox

Private Sub CheckBoxEvents_Click()
Dim Index As Long

' Get array index
 Index = frmReconcile.Frame1.ActiveControl.Caption
    If Index = 0 Or Index > ReconIndex Then
            MsgBox "CheckBoxEvents Index Out of Bounds"
            GoTo BYE
    End If
    
 If frmReconcile.Frame1.ActiveControl = True Then
            reArray(Index).reCleared = "R"
    Else
         reArray(Index).reCleared = ""
    End If

    ReconUncleared = 0#

' Recalc uncleared balance
    For Index = 1 To ReconIndex
            If reArray(Index).reCleared = "" Then
                    ReconUncleared = ReconUncleared + reArray(Index).reAmount
            End If
    Next Index

    frmReconcile.lblUncleared.Caption = Format(ReconUncleared, "##,###,##0.00")
    ReconCleared = ReconCurrBal - ReconUncleared
    frmReconcile.lblCleared.Caption = Format(ReconCleared, "##,###,##0.00")
    ReconDiff = ReconCleared - ReconStatementBal
    frmReconcile.lblDiff.Caption = Format(ReconDiff, "##,###,##0.00")
BYE:
End Sub
```

Here is the relevant code from the frmReconcile.

```
Dim AddLabel As Control
Dim AddCheckBox As Control
Dim checkArray() As New CheckBoxEvents

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim strType As String
Dim TrStartRow As Long
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim RowNum As Long
Dim Index As Long

Me.StartUpPosition = 0
Me.Left = getRegistry("frmReconcile:Left")
Me.Top = getRegistry("frmReconcile:Top")

Me.Height = 303
Me.Width = 563
    
On Error Resume Next
ReconCurrBal = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(Worksheets("Transactions").Range("Tr_Amount"), Range("Tr_Account"), ReconAccount)
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    MsgBox ("Account """ & ReconAccount & """ not found.")
    GoTo BYE
End If

lblBalance.Caption = Format(ReconCurrBal, "##,###,###,##0.00")

lblUncleared = Format(0, "##,###,##0.00")
lblCleared = Format(0, "##,###,##0.00")
lblStatementBal = Format(ReconStatementBal, "##,###,#0.00")
lblDiff = Format(0, "##,###,##0.00")

lblSortDateUp.Visible = False
lblSortPayeeUp.Visible = False
lblSortNumUp.Visible = False
lblSortAmountUp.Visible = False
lblSortSplitUp.Visible = False

' Clear filter
On Error Resume Next   'turn off error reporting
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Transactions").ShowAllData
On Error GoTo 0   'turn error reporting back on

' Set AutoFilter to get all transactions for Account where Recon equal to "c" or ""
TrStartRow = getRegistry("TrStartRow")
LastRow = GetLastRow("Transactions")
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Transactions").Range("$A$" & TrStartRow & ":K" & LastRow).AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:= _
    ReconAccount
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Transactions").Range("$A$" & TrStartRow & ":K" & LastRow).AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:="=c", _
    Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="="

' Find unreconciled transactions
Erase reArray
ReconUncleared = 0#
ReconIndex = 0
For RowNum = TrStartRow To LastRow
    With Worksheets("Transactions")
         If .Cells(RowNum, 2).Value = ReconAccount And .Cells(RowNum, 10).Value <> "R" Then
            ReconIndex = ReconIndex + 1
            reArray(ReconIndex).reDate = .Cells(RowNum, 1)
            reArray(ReconIndex).rePayee = .Cells(RowNum, 3)
            reArray(ReconIndex).reNum = .Cells(RowNum, 7)
            reArray(ReconIndex).reAmount = .Cells(RowNum, 5)
            reArray(ReconIndex).reSplit = .Cells(RowNum, 6)
            reArray(ReconIndex).reCleared = .Cells(RowNum, 10)
            reArray(ReconIndex).reRow = RowNum
        End If
    End With
Next RowNum

If ReconIndex = 0 Then
    MsgBox "No unreconciled transactions found for account """ & ReconAccount & """"
    GoTo BYE
End If

' Set sort buttons
lblSortDateUp.Visible = False
lblSortPayeeUp.Visible = False
lblSortNumUp.Visible = False
lblSortAmountUp.Visible = False
lblSortSplitUp.Visible = False

' Create controls
ReconUncleared = 0#
ReDim checkArray(ReconIndex)
For RowNum = 1 To ReconIndex
    Set AddLabel = Me.Frame1.Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1", "lblDate" & RowNum)
    With AddLabel
        .Top = 5 + (RowNum * 12 - 12)
        .Left = 6
        .Width = 48
        .BackColor = vbWhite
        .Caption = Format(reArray(RowNum).reDate, "mm/dd/yyyy")
    End With
    Set AddLabel = Me.Frame1.Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1", "lblPayee" & RowNum)
    With AddLabel
        .Top = 5 + (RowNum * 12 - 12)
        .Left = 60
        .Width = 102
        .BackColor = vbWhite
        .Caption = reArray(RowNum).rePayee
    End With
    Set AddLabel = Me.Frame1.Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1", "lblNum" & RowNum)
    With AddLabel
        .Top = 5 + (RowNum * 12 - 12)
        .Left = 168
        .Width = 24
        .BackColor = vbWhite
        .Caption = reArray(RowNum).reNum
    End With
    Set AddLabel = Me.Frame1.Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1", "lblAmount" & RowNum)
    With AddLabel
        .Top = 5 + (RowNum * 12 - 12)
        .Left = 198
        .Width = 60
        .BackColor = vbWhite
        .Caption = Format(reArray(RowNum).reAmount, "##,###,##0.00")
        .TextAlign = 3
    End With
    Set AddLabel = Me.Frame1.Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1", "lblSplit" & RowNum)
    With AddLabel
        .Top = 5 + (RowNum * 12 - 12)
        .Left = 264
        .Width = 60
        .BackColor = vbWhite
        .Caption = Format(reArray(RowNum).reSplit, "##,###,##0.00")
        .TextAlign = 3
    End With
    Set AddCheckBox = Me.Frame1.Controls.Add("Forms.CheckBox.1", "chkCleared" & RowNum)
    With AddCheckBox
        .Top = 5 + (RowNum * 12 - 14)
        .Left = 330
        .Caption = RowNum
        If reArray(RowNum).reCleared <> "" Then
            .Value = True
        End If
    End With

    Set checkArray(RowNum).CheckBoxEvents = AddCheckBox
    
Next RowNum

' Get uncleared balance
For Index = 1 To ReconIndex
    If reArray(Index).reCleared = "" Then
        ReconUncleared = ReconUncleared + reArray(Index).reAmount
    End If
Next Index

' Set labels
lblUncleared.Caption = Format(ReconUncleared, "##,###,##0.00")
ReconCleared = ReconCurrBal - ReconUncleared
lblCleared.Caption = Format(ReconCleared, "##,###,##0.00")
ReconDiff = ReconCleared - ReconStatementBal
lblDiff.Caption = Format(ReconDiff, "##,###,##0.00")

Frame1.ScrollHeight = ReconIndex * 20
Frame1.ScrollTop = 0

BYE:
If ReconIndex = 0 Then Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)

If CloseMode = vbFormControlMenu Then
    Cancel = True
    Call cmdCancel_Click
End If

Erase reArray
ReconAccount = ""
ReconIndex = 0
ReconCurrBal = 0#
ReconUncleared = 0#
ReconCleared = 0#
ReconStatementBal = 0#
ReconDiff = 0#

Call saveRegistry("frmReconcile:Left", Me.Left)
Call saveRegistry("frmReconcile:Top", Me.Top)

Call Reset

End Sub
```

Comment: When you say "I get the error after the Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose", do you really mean **after**? Is there a code yellow line where the code stops?  If not, try running the part of the code which leads to this ending line by line, using F8. Only in this way you will see the problematic code line. Sometimes, when a `Sub` tries calling a function from the form and this one return an error, the error is moved to the function call...

Comment: FaneDuru - In the QueryClose routine, I added a msgbox before the End Sub. Once I click ok on the msgbox I get the error. I will try the set through with F8.

Comment: If you're not getting to see the problem line when clicking Debug then make sure you have your VBA error handling set to "Break in class module"

Comment: @TimWilliams - Thank you for the response.  I set Break in Class module but no luck. The debugger doesn't trap the actual error.

Comment: I was able to solve the problem. I was checking to see if there was transactions to be reconciled in the Initiate event. If no transactions were found I was unloading the form. that is where the problem was.  It seems you cannot unload a form during the Initiate event. When I move the code to the Activate event it resolved the issue.